# Не срабатывает конструктор копирования c++

Tags: c++, конструктор-копирования

Пишу свой класс для длинной арифметики(просто практикуюсь). Перегрузил оператор +, написал конструктор копирования. При попытке вывода cout << a+b компилятор сначала складывает числа, затем сразу пытается вывести ответ, хотя конструктор копирования даже не срабатывает, и в итоге ничего не выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class infinite {
public:
    infinite() {
        this->maxlen = 30;
        this->arr = new int[maxlen] {};
        cout << "конструктор" << &arr << endl;
    }
    infinite(string prototype, int len, int maxlen) {
        this->len = len;
        this->maxlen = maxlen;
        this->arr = new int[maxlen] {};
        int j = len-1;
        for (int i = maxlen - 1; j<prototype.length(); i--, j--) {
            arr[i] = prototype[j] - '0';
        }
        cout << "конструктор" << &arr << endl;
    }
    infinite(const infinite &other) {
        this->maxlen = other.maxlen;
        this->len = other.len;
        this->arr = new int[other.maxlen]{};
        for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen-other.len; i--) {
            this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
        }
        cout << "конструктор копирования" << &arr << endl;
    }
    ~infinite() {
        delete[] arr;
        cout << "деструктор" << &arr << endl;
    }



    infinite & operator = (const infinite &other) {
        if (this->arr != nullptr) {
            delete[] this->arr;
        }
        this->maxlen = other.maxlen;
        this->len = other.len;
        this->arr = new int[other.maxlen]{};
        for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen - other.len - 1; i--) {
            this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    infinite & operator + (const infinite &other) {
        infinite temp;
        if (this->len > other.len) {
            temp.len = this->len;
            temp.maxlen = this->maxlen;
            temp.arr = new int[this->maxlen];
            for (int i = this->maxlen - 1; i > this->maxlen - this->len - 1; i--) {
                if (this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] > 9) {
                    if (i == this->maxlen - this->len - 1) {
                        len++;
                        arr[i - 1] == 1;
                    }
                    temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] - 10;
                }
                else {
                    temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            temp.len = other.len;
            temp.maxlen = other.maxlen;
            temp.arr = new int[other.maxlen];
            for (int i = other.maxlen - 1; i > other.maxlen - other.len - 1; i--) {
                if (this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] > 9) {
                    if (i == other.maxlen - other.len - 1) {
                        len++;
                        arr[i - 1] == 1;
                    }
                    temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i] - 10;
                }
                else {
                    temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i] + other.arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "сложение" << &arr << endl;
        return temp;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const infinite &that) {
        cout << "вывод" << endl;
        for (int i = that.maxlen - 1; i > that.maxlen - that.len - 1; i--) {
            os << that.arr[i];
        }
        return os;
    }

private:
    int len;
    int maxlen;
    int *arr;
};

void f() {
    string prototype;
    cin >> prototype;
    infinite a(prototype, prototype.length(), 30);
    cin >> prototype;
    infinite b(prototype, prototype.length(), 30);
    cout << a + b;


}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");


    f();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор сложения возвращает битую ссылку на объект, который вышел из области видимости, вместо возвращения нового объекта.

```
infinite operator +
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!